# Always getting error with foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

Whenever I set a foreign key, I get the below error, and I'm not sure why. Can someone help me figure it out?

```
Error
SQL query: ALTER TABLE  `vl_discount` ADD CONSTRAINT  `vl_product_ibfk1` FOREIGN KEY (  `discountedProduct` )
REFERENCES  `base`.`vl_product` (`autokey`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
MySQL said: Documentation
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`base`.`#sql41d_172`, CONSTRAINT `vl_product_ibfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`discountedProduct`)
REFERENCES `vl_product` (`autokey`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: Error tells you exactly whats wrong. You're trying to update a table without updating the foreign keys it's attached to. Add your database schema and query that you're trying to run to this question for further help.

Comment: some row in `discountedProduct` column has a reference to a non existent id in vl_product

Comment: but my vl_product is existing

Comment: do something like this to see which row is failing your constraint. `select vl_discount.discountedProduct from vl_discount left join vl_product on vl_discount.discountedProduct = vl_product.autokey where vl_product.autokey is null`

Comment: i tried it already but i gave me this [result](https://38.media.tumblr.com/6d7ec8333d1a708fbc090600651805cd/tumblr_n9i27tF0gx1rdurp3o1_1280.png)